# Heights and margins rendered differently on Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I find the following differences in chrome and safari while making a webpage.

Chrome

[image]

Safari
[image]

There are minor differences in the height and width of the white card and the phone and also there is a significant difference while setting margins for the github button.

I have used % as the unit everywhere. Could anyone point out why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="layer container-3" data-depth="0.8">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="images/phone.png" class="phone-img">
                    <img src="images/checkOnGithub.svg" class="github-button">
                </div>
</div>
```

The `.layer` and `data-depth` attribute come from the `parallax.js` plugin. I have also used the `fullPage.js` plugin - just in case.

CSS:

```
.container-4 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    top: 9% !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.phone-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
    height: 150%;
    width: auto;
    top: -18%;
    left: -46%;
}

.card {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 58%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 45%;
    top: 22.5%;
    left: 35%;
    border-top-right-radius: 18px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 18px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.github-button {
    margin-top: 52%;
    right: 18%;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 18%;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    margin-right: 15%;
}
```

Comment: because they render html differently?. use a css reset

Comment: If everything is in %, the result depends on the size of the browser window. Are you sure those sizes are the same? (The screenshot heights aren't.) And things like `top-margin` in % are relative to the width of the container, not the height.

Comment: @vbouk - I am using normalize.css, could you shed a little more light on css reset - i am not familiar with it.

Comment: I belive this is because you're mixing relative positioning and absolute position values such as top / left / ...   try using relative positioning with margins or absolute positioning with top/left/right/bottom, the result across browsers should be more consistent.

Comment: @PierreBurton - Ok i will try that out

Comment: @MrLister - I have opened all browsers on full-screen mode, and the zoom value is also the same. So that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @PierreBurton - i tried what you suggested, there is still a significant difference between the two